# SQLite overwrites my existing records : C++

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am new to SQLite and I may be missing something very basic. I am creating a table as shown below with the following statement.

### Creation of Table statement

```
std::string strQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ";
    strQuery += tableNames[msgTable];
    strQuery += " (RecKey INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Origin TEXT NOT NULL, Type INT, Target INT, Header TEXT NOT NULL, Content TEXT)";
```

Then I am inserting records using the following statement.

### Insert statement

```
std::string appendRecStr = "INSERT INTO " + tableNames[msg._type] + " (RecKey, Origin, Type, Target, Header, Content) VALUES (";
    appendRecStr +=  std::string("NULL") + ", " +
                     AddQuote4SQL(msg._orig) +", " + 
                     AddQuote4SQL((short)msg._type) +", " + 
                     AddQuote4SQL((short)msg._target) +", " + 
                     AddQuote4SQL(msg._head) +", " + 
                     AddQuote4SQL(msg._data) + ");";
```

Also,

```
    inline std::string AddQuote4SQL( const std::string & s ) {return std::string("'") + s + 
    std::string("'");}
inline std::string AddQuote4SQL( short s ) 
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "'" << std::to_string(s) << "'";
        return ss.str();
    }
```

The problem is the insert statement overwrites existing records. What is going wrong?

Comment: You must separate SQL issues from client-language issues! Have your C++ program output the actual SQL queries which are sent to the database; test those queries in the SQLite command-line client, fix them there, *then* incorporate them into your C++ code. This allows you to know if it's an SQL problem or a C++ problem in the first place. Does step 1 produce the query you expected? If not, you have a C++ problem. Does step 1 produce the expected query but the result of the query when executed in the command-line client is not what you wanted? Then you have an SQL problem.

Comment: Related: If this is an attempt at hardening inputs for a SQL execution, it is woefully inadequate. You should be using a prepared statement in the first place. See [the API docs](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html), and read the sample snippets. There are plenty of them.

Comment: The code you've shown just constructs a string. Show the code that executes the command.

Comment: Thanks Christian and Craig. I found a bug in my code and it now works fine.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing indeed something basic about sql here. An INSERT statement always inserts a new row. What you want in this case is an UPDATE statement, which uses a certain value to recognize its a duplicate (i.e. column1 = "somevalue": below). In case no rows are found that match the value, you should insert, since no duplicates exist. See code below:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET (...) WHERE Column1='SomeValue'
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
    INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (...)
```

Comment: Not sure I follow.
My current Statement is "INSERT INTO Table1 (...) VALUES (...);"

Comment: Unfortunately, INSERT statement in my code is not adding a new row! I do not want to update. That is exactly my problem. It seems to overwrite existing row.